# iMac WiFi connection to my router is unstable

Tags: wifi, network, imac

I got an iMac about half a year ago (2011 version). It has been fine, until recent weeks. Now the iMac loses its connection to my wireless router frequently. I have to turn off WiFi on the iMac and turn it on again to reconnect.

First I thought it might be the problem of my wireless router. However, in the same room, my Macbook Air and iPad work just fine.

I've done all the software update available. Still doesn't work.

What can I do to fix the problem? Any idea?

Comment: What's AP? Do you mean Airport?

Comment: Wireless access point from my ISP. BTW I'm in Canada and my ISP is Rogers.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running? Snow Leopard or Lion?

Comment: @WheatWilliams I'm running Lion.

Comment: @WheatWilliams after upgrading to Mountain Lion, the same issue occurs again. Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

The problem resolved after installing the newest Wi-Fi update.
http://www.macrumors.com/2012/02/24/apple-releases-imac-wi-fi-update-v1-0/

EDIT: after upgrading to Mountain Lion, the same issue occurs again. Anybody encounters the same problem?

Tried to install http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1501. But the package prompt out that 'The package require OS X 10.7' which means not be able to install on 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this issue has something to do with your ISP, since the only mater is the WLAN module of your router.

It might be a hardware problem in iMac: i've got similar issues where actually the antenna of the wlan-module was broken.

You could also try to change the WLAN channel (set it fix to some between [1..13]) and see what happens.

Comment: Where is the WLAN configuration? That's for my iMac or router?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, I deleted the network interface in network properties then re-made it, so far this seems to of fixed the issue.

Comment: I tried deleting the wifi interface in the network preference and added it later, but it doesn't work for me. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yea it is what I meant, what OS are you using? Do you use Bootcamp because I noticed the interface only kept disconnecting on the OSX Boot not Bootcamp.

Comment: I use Lion without Bootcamp.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the issue is with Lion's 10.7.3 update that came out a few weeks ago. It was *supposed* to fix the wifi issue that other people were having. However, I never started having the issue until after I installed the update.

Comment: Maybe I should wait for next update or try to install Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this Apple KB article [Troubleshooting Wi-Fi issues in OS X Lion and Mac OS X v10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4628)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Whilst your answer may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the article in an answer below, and provide the link for reference